# Upload .csv file to salesforce without converting its original encoding

Tags: apex, csv, conversion, encodingutil

I have created a functionality wherein I can upload a csv to salesforce. The problem I have at the moment is that when I try to upload an ANSI encoding, an error will occur 'Blob is not a valid UTF-8 string'. How can I upload my file using apex without modifying the current file encoding ? I've tried to use some answers in the internet but it didn't solve my issue. Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. It will help you.

```
    oppList = new List<opportunity>();
    HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
    tmp.setBodyAsBlob(csvFileBody.body);
    csvAsString = tmp.getBody();
    csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');


    for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
        string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');

   }
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much this really solve my problem. Can I ask you what is the explanation of this ?

Comment: @Hope In this way HttpRequest convert the encoding. Actually  I also face same issue and use this solution. That's all info i have. Glad this helps.